# Python: How to create conditions at every start of year for daily time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

In Python, I have a daily interval time-series dataset. **How can I iterate through it to do certain calculations at every start of the year?**

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data = df.values.tolist()
```

snapshot of data (it's actually longer, limited here for brevity sake) :

```
[['2007-01-03', 70.57, 0.0, 70.57, 89.22, 0.0, 89.22, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 63.58, 24.27], ['2007-01-02', 72.6, 1.2970000000000002, 73.50789999999999, 93.25, 3.4570000000000003, 95.6699, 105.66, 3.2920000000000003, 107.9644, 83.56, 32.06]]
```

How can I write a code in a for loop that **sets a condition at every start of the year?**

```
for row in data:
   date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
   Stocks = row[1]
   if date == ??:
      Stocks = Stocks * 2.5
```

Comment: ````Date      | VTI    | TLT     |  IEI  | GLD    | DBC |
2007-01-03 | 70.57 | 89.22  | 100 | 63.58   | 24.7 |
2007-01-04 | 70.58 | 89.24  | 102 | 63.54   | 24.4 |
2007-01-05 | 70.58 | 89.26  | 103 | 63.55   | 24.6 |````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need minimal datetimes per years, so use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
first = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)['date'].min().tolist()
```

And then test by:

```
   if date in first:
      Stocks = Stocks * 2.5
```